# How to refresh DataGrid?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, refresh, wcf-ria-services

I am working on Silverlight 5 and RIA Services for database operations. DataGrid showing data perfectly.

But when I delete a record and submit changes to database, database updating successfully, but DataGrid showing still old data. It is not refreshing.

I search on google and surprise to see that there is no simple answer and I am also surprise to see that microsoft has not provided this basic functionality in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good way by anymeans, but I have gotten around this by setting the DataGrid to null and the re-adding the data.

```
 System.Collections.IEnumerable temp = yourGrid.ItemsSource;
 yourGrid.ItemsSource = null;
 yourGrid.ItemsSource = temp;
```

I do not like doing it this way but it works and for my purposes I have not noticed any performance hits.

Edit: I guess this may not work with a delete though, but worth a try

Comment: What you will say about this missing basic feature in silverlight. Does it not surprise you?

Comment: No it really does surprise me, but in all my searching online and trials this was the only way that I could get it to work.  It is hard for me to believe that no one thought a refresh() or invalidate() would be a good idea, but it doesn't appear to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an PagedCollectionView as ItemSource?

Something like:

```
DataGridMainTopic.ItemsSource = new PagedCollectionView(m_context.EntitySet);
```

or even:

```
DataGridMainTopic.ItemsSource = new PagedCollectionView(DataGridMainTopic.ItemsSource);
```